# Simulation making using MFC application

Tags: mfc, simulation

I am doing a simulation using MFC application (its a robot moving in a field) what happens is that the process behind calculates the position to quick where as drawing takes time so what I see ultimately is the robot at the end position no intermediate positions . But when I put AFXMessageBox then I can see all the position its been going through , Can you help me figure this out

Answer (score 0):

Hina, What you need to do is move the complex calculation that calculates the position of the robot to a thread and keep the drawing of robot in your main thread. Then you need to communicate your current positions to the main thread and after the drawing invalidate your surface. This way you can see the positions updated frequently.

What happens when you display a message box is you are able to repaint the surface after the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

You can fasten the drawing my using memory device context. In a nutshell you would do all the drawing on a bitmap in memory which will be fast. When it is all ready, you will print the final drawing on your display. This will be very fast and smooth.